# Using TOR multiple times (Tor in Tor)

Tags: anonymity, vpn

### What if i run tor trough tor?

I have seen it somewhere stating that it can destroy your anonimity but i doubt it.

All the other circuit is going to do is protect the end nodes anonimity like its a client, right?
And running tor to vpn easily links all of my activity to one account even while tor changes its circuit and ip every 10 minutes? I just didnt find that noted.

{Tor{VPN{Tor{VPN{Tor}}}} will be slow i know that but if the first and the last vpns are malicious could they see that its the same trafic even while its encrypted? And if yes how?

And i need the most anonimity i can get what is the beest way IN YOUR OPINION for that? I dont need stuff like turn of javascript etc just the best way to make my IP anonymous as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate - the Question Linked on June 2nd 2015 was definitly not the Question @OFFICER asked (in my Opinion) - also Interesting Question. He is new here, so let me help him.